# Paypal payment execute transaction refused

Tags: paypal

Everything is good at sandbox environment, but something wrong in production.

First, i created a payment with enough information. It's still good.

Second, I redirect to apprvoved url for end user, user accepted payment.

Lastly, i make a request execute payment within payerId, but i received response error, it's return 400 and message name TRANSACTION_REFUSED.
Anyone help me!

Detail payment: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI5fZ.png)

Detail error: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvsTd.png)

Answer (score 0):

The payment attempt was rejected by PayPal. This error is normal behavior when a payment is declined.

Have the user use a different account or payment method.

---

Unrelated to the decline issue, you are using a deprecated v1/payments API, which should not be used for any new integrations. Here is how to change to a current v2/checkout/orders integration:

Make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server